# How to use content object of CreatedAtRoute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I use the object sending via CreatedAtRoute without recreating?

For Example:

```
return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetUserById), new { Id = userReadDto.Id }, userReadDto);
```

I want to use userReadDto object without recreating in:

```
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetUserById")]
        public ActionResult<UserReadDto> GetUserById(int id)
        {
            var user = _repository.GetUserById(id);
            if (user != null)
                return Ok(_mapper.Map<UserReadDto>(user));
            else
                return NotFound();
        }
```

Comment: `CreatedAtRoute` is for specifying a route, perhaps you want `Created` instead? Also, what do you mean by "without recreating"? Without recreating what exactly?

Comment: I meant I already sent an object, how do I use it in GetUserById without rederiving?
soryy for grammar rules.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use content object of CreatedAtRoute?

You could check the definition about the [CreatedAtRoute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdatroute?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

[image]

As we can see that, the first parameter is the route Name, instead of the action name. You could check the following code to the CreatedAtRoute method:

In the Startup.Configure method, create a single route and named "default":

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {  
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index2}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            
        });
```

Then, in the controller, we could use the CreatedAtRoute method like this:

```
 return CreatedAtRoute("default", new { Id = 101 }, result); //the first parameter is the route name.
```

According to your code, I assume you want navigate to the GetUserById action method and transfer the data (userReadDto) between action methods. If that is the case, you could use the [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method, code as below:

```
TempData.Put("data",result); //using TempData or Session to store the data.
return RedirectToAction(nameof(GetUserById), new { Id = userReadDto.Id });
```

Then, in the GetUserById method

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetUserById")]
    public ActionResult<UserReadDto> GetUserById(int id)
    {
        var data = TempData.Get<List<UserReadDto>>("data");

        var user = _repository.GetUserById(id);
        if (user != null)
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<UserReadDto>(user));
        else
            return NotFound();
    }
```

[Note] The above code using TempDate to store the object data, you have to add a TempDataHelper with the following code:

```
//required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
//required using System.Text.Json;
public static class TempDataHelper
{
    public static void Put<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        tempData[key] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out object o);
        return o == null ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>((string)o);
    }

    public static T Peek<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        object o = tempData.Peek(key);
        return o == null ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>((string)o);
    }
}
```

More detail information about using TempData and Session, check [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0)